# How to reshape a dataset in order to make it sequential?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have a classic dataset of images and labels.

Here is a simple representation of the `__getitem__` function :

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
        (img_path, label) = df.iloc[index].values
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        y = torch.tensor(labels))

        return (img, y)
```

I have :

```
dataset = ClassDataset()
train_set, validation_set = random_split(dataset)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_set)
```

The size of one batch of the train loader would be : `[32,3,256,256]`
With 32 being the batch size, 3 the number of channels and 256 the width and height of my image.

I want to modify the shape of one batch so that it is sequential `[8,4,3,256,256]` with 8 being the batch size and 4 the length of one sequence.
I know that it could be easily done with `torch.view()` or `torch.reshape()` knowing that my data are already in the right order (they can be grouped directly into sequences).
But I want to know where is the most intelligent place to make this change, in the dataset class, in the dataloader class or in the train loop.
I already tried passing sequences into the getitem :

```
(img_path, coords) = df.iloc[4*(index-1):4*index].values
```

(assuming that sequence length is 4), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more relevant to do this kind of processing in the dataset layer. Indeed, what you are looking to implement there is *"given a dataset index `index` return the corresponding input and its label"*. In your case you are dealing with a sequence as input, so something like this makes sense for your `__getitem__` to return a sequence of images.

The data loader will automatically collate the data such that you get `(batch_size, seq_len, channel, height, width)` for your input, and `(batch_size, seq_len)` for your label (or `(batch_size,)` if there is meant to be a single label per sequence).

Comment: The problem i am facing is that the getitem iterates over indexes of my dataset. So if my dataset is len 100 and i have a seq len of 4, I am having empy lists above 25 (because 25*4 >= 100)

Comment: You could just consider your dataset with a length of `100-seq_length` items and when retrieving an element, say `__getitem__(index)`, you are in fact returning elements `|index, index+1, ... index+seq_len-1]`. Alternatively, if you want your sequence to not be overlapping, then consider changing the length of your dataset to `floor(100%seq_len)`.

Comment: It worked. I didn't have the idea of modifying the `__len__` directly. Now have my sequences well fed into the LSTM. Thanks !
And i am padding my sequences so that they have seq_len*N elements, thus I don't have any overlapping issues ;)